# How can I loop a case switch statement if an invalid value is chosen i.e the default

Tags: c#

Here is an example where a menu of values is available. i would like to have it loop back to the start if none of the options are chosen.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("1 : Option 1");
    Console.WriteLine("2 : Option 2");
    Console.WriteLine("3 : Option 3");
    Console.WriteLine("4 : Option 4");
    Console.WriteLine("5 : Option 5");
    Console.Write("Please enter your option choice: ");
    string choice = Console.ReadLine();

    int intChoice = int.Parse(choice);
    switch (intChoice)
    {
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("you chose 1");
            break;
        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine("you chose 2");
            break;
        case 3:
            Console.WriteLine("you chose 3");
            break;
        case 4:
            Console.WriteLine("you chose 4");
            break;
        case 5:
            Console.WriteLine("you chose 5");
            break;
    }
}
```

I've tried to do it through using classes and method, but i just got really confused.

thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: That's not how switch statements work. You'll have to wrap the whole thing around a `while` or `for` loop

Comment: As an aside (and as shown in Heather's example below) you might want to consider using int.TryParse to check that 'choice' can indeed be converted to an int. You could continue to use int.Parse, but would have to wrap it in a try/catch block - right now an invalid choice could terminate the app with an unhandled exception.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the whole thing in a `do-while` block:

```
bool isValid = true;

do
{
    isValid = true;
    // Write to console
    // read from console
    switch(intChoice)    
    {
        // Place some cases here.
        default: 
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Choice")
            isValid = false;
    }
}
while(!isValid);
```

Comment: After first invalid input, flag will be set to false, you need to set it back to true on every loop

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean value as a flipswitch that tell the `while` loop to continue running or not. Here's a small example:

```
bool stillRunning = true;

while (stillRunning)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number.");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    int key = Convert.ToInt32(input);

    switch (key)
    {
        case 1:
            // Do something.
            stillRunning = false;
            break;

        case 2:
            // Do something.
            stillRunning = false;
            break;

        default:
            Console.WriteLine("No key selected.");
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use default

```
    switch (intChoice)
    {
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("you chose 1");
            break;
        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine("you chose 2");
            break;
        ....... 
        default: 
            //your logic here
            break;
    }
```

it is your choice after that how you like to do it. you can use a while and a Boolean value like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("1 : Option 1");
            Console.WriteLine("2 : Option 2");
            Console.WriteLine("3 : Option 3");
            Console.WriteLine("4 : Option 4");
            Console.WriteLine("5 : Option 5");
            Console.Write("Please enter your option choice: ");


            bool correct = true;

            while (correct)
            {
                string choice = Console.ReadLine();
                int intChoice = int.Parse(choice);
                switch (intChoice)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("you chose 1");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("you chose 2");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Console.WriteLine("you chose 3");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Console.WriteLine("you chose 4");
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        Console.WriteLine("you chose 5");
                        break;
                    default:
                        correct = false;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious solution seems to be:

```
bool loop = true;

while (loop)
{
    loop = false;
    switch (Console.ReadLine())
    {
        case "1":
            Console.WriteLine("you chose 1");
            break;
        case "2":
            Console.WriteLine("you chose 2");
            break;
        case "3":
            Console.WriteLine("you chose 3");
            break;
        case "4":
            Console.WriteLine("you chose 4");
            break;
        case "5":
            Console.WriteLine("you chose 5");
            break;
        default:
            loop = true;
            break;
    }
}
```

There could be a better way to do this though.

Answer (score 0):

Thus you need only one number, it's better to use `GetKey` method, then reading `string` value from console and then parsing it to `int`:

```
DisplayOptions();
bool choiceDone;

do
{
    choiceDone = true;

    switch(GetChoice())
    {
       case ConsoleKey.D1:
           Console.WriteLine("you chose 1");
           break;
       case ConsoleKey.D2:
           Console.WriteLine("you chose 2");
           break;
           // etc
       default:
           choiceDone = false;
           break;
    }

} while(!choiceDone);
```

Also I have extracted several methods, to make code more clean:

```
private ConsoleKey GetChoice()
{
     Console.Write("Please enter your option choice: ");
     return Console.ReadKey().Key;
}

private void DisplayOptions()
{
     Console.Clear();
     Console.WriteLine("1 : Option 1");
     Console.WriteLine("2 : Option 2");
     Console.WriteLine("3 : Option 3");
     Console.WriteLine("4 : Option 4");
     Console.WriteLine("5 : Option 5");
}
```

Comment: this is sort of what i tried with the methods, but i'm still not sure how to actually use this. or understand the key part.

Comment: You can read about `Console.ReadKey` on msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readkey.aspx Also you are free to ask about methods. What is not clear to you?

Comment: do i have to put them into a class to call them? when i've been trying with the code you used as an example i get an error asking for a reference.

Comment: @n00blearner put first code block into `Main` method. Then paste other two methods under your `Main` method (inside `Program` class). And last step - add word `static` to both methods definition. Like this: `private static void DisplayOptions()`

Answer (score 0):

```
public void GetInput()
{
    int inputValue = 0;
    bool isValidInput = false;
    List<int> validEntries = new List<int> { 1,2,3, 42, 55, 69};

    while (!isValidInput)
        isValidInput = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out inputValue) && validEntries.Contains(inputValue);

    switch (inputValue)
    {
        case 1:
            {
                // something
                break;
            }
        case 2:
            {
                // something else
                break;
            }
        default:
            {
                //yet something else
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

Edit: Added explicit value check instead of accepting any integer.